# In .NET 3.5, how can I determine which image is being displayed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried this:

```
if(PauseButton.Image != global::GripAIConsole.Icons.Resume)
{
    PauseButton.Image = global::GripAIConsole.Icons.Resume;
    ToolTipMainWin.SetToolTip(PauseButton, "Resume / Step <F4>");
}
```

And it doesn't work. I would have thought it was comparing pointers internally to see if they were pointing at the same place.

Comment: Are you sure both `PauseButton.Image` and `global::GripAIConsole.Icons.Resume` point to the same reference? How do you know?

Comment: Why are you using the image to determine the state of the program?

Comment: I'm using the image state because if it worked, it would be the easiest thing to do. If I do PauseButton.Image = global::GripAIConsole.Icons.Resume, I expect that to be the same reference as global::GripAIConsole.Icons.Resume.

Comment: Sounds like a bad assumption. Also, what platform are you talking about? Winforms? XNA?

Comment: What type is `global::GripAIConsole.Icons.Resume`? Is it a value type or reference type?

Comment: Winforms. I agree with everyone that this is probably a bad idea. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with resources, so if you want to make sure the reference is right, compare using the static method `Object.ReferenceEquals()`. As ChrisF said, you should not use this to determine application logic. Using a simple bool variable is much better (and slightly more performance friendly).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of ReferenceEquals, but so everyone knows, I won't use it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I would define the possible states with an enum:

```
public enum State {
    Stopped,
    Pausing,
    Running
}
```

And then define a state property or variable:

```
State _state;
```

then Change the states as follows:

```
void ChangeState(State newState)
{
    _state = newState;
    switch (newState) {
        case State.Stopped:
            PauseButton.Image = global::GripAIConsole.Icons.Pause;
            ToolTipMainWin.SetToolTip(PauseButton, "Start game <F5>");
            break;
        case State.Pausing:
            PauseButton.Image = global::GripAIConsole.Icons.Resume;
            ToolTipMainWin.SetToolTip(PauseButton, "Resume / Step <F4>");
            break;
        case State.Running:
            PauseButton.Image = global::GripAIConsole.Icons.Pause;
            ToolTipMainWin.SetToolTip(PauseButton, "Pause <F4> / Stop game <F6>");
            break;
    }
}
```

... or whatever your logic requires.

This is much cleaner and understandable. A picture has to do with the GUI, not with the logic. Inferring the state of the logic from things displayed on the forms is weird.